# Cloud Bursting using CloudFoundry on vagrant with Bosh-lite

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

**What we want to do**

- We want to setup a POC lab environment in our organization for cloud foundry PAAS environment, for that we are using vagrant with bosh-lite.
- Next we want to cloud burst(port) one sample application from our local environment to public cloud(with cloud foundry) on the fly once a condition is met (like request going above threshold count).

**What we have done**

We have installed vagrant and bosh-lite on Ubuntu. using instruction from below url http://dmunozfer.es/como-instalar-cloud-foundry-en-local-ubuntu/
  (please translate)

Now we want to install cloud foundry.

**Problem Statement**

1. we are trying to install cloudfoundry v193 but we are unable to get
   any documentation in cloudfoundry.org specifying content and architecture of older (pre-diego) cloudfoundary, since all docs are updated to diego version.
2. Blogs are stating that pivotal is pushing user from their public cloud to upgrade and port their application for latest cloudfoundry deployments.

   Are other public cloud provider (like Amazon and Azure) doing the same ??
3. We have a confusion on which version of cloudfoundry to install,
   since there is shift in architecture from older version to Diego
   version(latest). Also we believe we need to have same version of
   cloudfoundry in both local and public cloud for cloud bursting. Considering the fact that soon all public clouds will be on diego cloudfoundry version. Can we still use v193 on our local deployment, if we want cloud bursting to work between our local deployment and public cloud ??

Please suggest which version we should use and if possible please guide how to install it.

Also can someone point us to a link which explains how we can cloud burst our application from our local deployment to a public cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

For local a local easy installation of cloudfoundry, pcf-dev is quite handy. This should be a quite recent version of Diego compatible with public PCF installations.

https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev